# Web Page Contact Info Hidden From Web Craulers

Tags: php, web-crawler

I know that there are engines crawling the internet looking for email addresses on websites and one way to avoid that is having the contact info as image.
Is it also safe to insert the contact info with php code? In other words, does web crawlers "see" the page as it is on the server (with the php code) or as it shown on the browser with all the information after execution of the php code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crawlers see the HTML generated, not the PHP source code. It'd be better to obfuscate email addresses with JavaScript.